# EWS Java API - Connection error

Tags: ewsjavaapi

I think I've exhausted my options on this one. I have searched over the internet for days and couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

I'm using the EWS Java API 1.2.1 to connect to an Exchange server and open my inbox folder to look for emails. Here is my code:

```
import java.net.URI;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.*;

public class Connection {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("myUser", "myPass");

        service.setCredentials(credentials);

        service.setUrl(new URI("https://example.com/ews/exchange.asmx"));

        service.setTraceEnabled(true);

        Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceLocalException: https://example.com/ews/exchange.asmx : Connection error 
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeServiceBase.prepareHttpWebRequestForUrl(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.prepareHttpWebRequest(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.buildEwsHttpWebRequest(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder.bind(Unknown Source)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder.bind(Unknown Source)
at Connection.main(Connection.java:22)
```

I thought it could be something blocking my connection attempt but it does work with the above URL and User credentials when I use the JWebServices API.

BTW, I can also access the WSDL from my browser.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be because of the wrong JARs referenced to this Class.

What are the JARs you are using. And which version of EWS API is used here.??

I faced this same Problem while using EWS API 1.2, after referring the following JARs, it got resolved.

EWSJavaAPI_1.2original.jar,
EWSJavaAPIWithJars_1.2.1.jar,
httpclient-4.2.5.jar,
httpcore-4.2.4.jar,
jcifs-1.3.17.jar,
commons-codec-1.7.jar,
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

EWSJavaAPI_1.2original.jar - This is having the microsoft related Classes
EWSJavaAPIWithJars_1.2.1.jar - This one is having its Connection related Classes.

Try adding these JARs.

Regards,
Ramesh G.